# API requires JWT Token on all requests despite the authentication configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am attempting to follow this [tutorial](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt-mysql), which is a follow up to this [tutorial](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt), to implement JWT authorization for my API. When I attempt to use the '/authenticate' and '/register', I get the error "JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String".

Here is the part of the Request filter that throws the error:

```
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
    }
```

Here is the websecurityconfig that should be allowing the 'authenticate' and 'request' requests through. I'm a bit confused as I cannot find where this is actually called in the tutorial:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Attached is a link to the github.

https://github.com/Dikianify/ReporterAPI.git

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the jwtRequestFilter is a filter it will be **called on every request** (including /authenticate & /register), not just those that require authentication.

```
httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

This is not a problem because the code is simply writing a warning to the logs and passing the request on down for further processing.

```
logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
```

When the user has been authenticated the Bearer header with the token should come through in each request for the filter to extract username.

Comment: When I attempt to use '/register' to make a new user, I am still getting a 401 unauthorized status code. Any ideas as to the cause of this?

Comment: No, try .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate**", "/register**").permitAll()